# Scheduled cron Python script logging working differently than it does when run manually

Tags: python, cron

I have a Python script that is running as a cron job every day. I'm trying to get it to only output when necessary so that cron doesn't email me unless there is a warning or error. However, DEBUG-level output is still being emailed to me, even though I've set the logging level to WARNING.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
```

When I run the script through IDLE this works as intended with no output. (If I omit those two lines, I get a bunch of DEBUG output). But when the script runs through the cron schedule, I'm being emailed those DEBUG lines.

My crontab is simple:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
0 6 * * * python3 /home/pi/script.py
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `cron` may run as different user, with different settings and privilages, in different folder and it may not have access to display.

Comment: often `cron` is configured to send email when script display error - or you have to redirect standard outpu to some file or `/dev/null` - ie. `python3 /home/pi/script.py > /dev/null` or even redirect standard error `python3 /home/pi/script.py > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: [How do I completely silence a cronjob to /dev/null/?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100722/how-do-i-completely-silence-a-cronjob-to-dev-null)

Comment: Thank you @furas. I do want Cron to email me, but only if there *is* an output. I just don't understand why there would be an output from this script, as there isn't any when I run it manually.

Comment: do you use `print()` ? it also generate output. BTW: you could send to mail all settings - maybe it doesn't have `WARNING` level. As I know `logging` sometimes works different then we expect. If you use `basicConfing` then later you can't change logging level. every handler (ie. handler to send to file, handler to send on console) has also own level assigned - so sometimes you have to change both levels (level for handler and global level) to get expected result. BTW: I don't know if environment setting may change logging level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was setting the default logging level *after* importing the module that was automatically generating that debug output. Kind of obvious now.